# Get elements with a certain generic type in a list

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I am currently working on a train project and I have following question:

I save all rolling stock in a list:
To understand my class hierarchy better, here is a simplified inheritance overview:

```
RollingStock
    Engine
        SteamEngine
        DieselEngine
        ...
    Coach
        FreightCoach
        PassengerCoach
        ...
    TrainSet
```

In my register, I want to save all rolling stock in a list `private List<RollingStock> rollingStock;`. So far, I have created a list for each rolling stock type (engines, coaches, trainSets). However, I need to delete a certain rolling stock with just its ID and therefore it's easier to save everything in just one list.

As of before, I created an engine like this:

```
    public void createEngine(Engine engine) {
        this.engines.add(engine);
    }
```

Now, with just one list I do it like this:

```
    public void createEngine(Engine engine) {
        this.rollingStocks.add(engine);
    }
```

This works perfectly fine. For the returnEngines() method I don't seem to find a solution:

It was as easy as this with one list for each rolling stock type:

```
    public List<Engine> returnEngines() {
        return engines;
    }
```

Now, I have to filter all engines out of the rolling stock list:

```
    public List<Engine> returnEngines() {
        ...
        return rollingStock.???;

    }
```

I could add the method `public String getType()` and check for its type.

I can't imagine that there isn't a better solution.

How can this be done?

Comment: Is there any value in the order of the stock in your stock lists? If not, I think you might be better off using `Set`s. The other suggestion I have is that if you want collections of Engines and Rolling Stock (etc) you could make Rolling Stock a synthetic collection, made up internally of other collections.

Comment: What would be the advantage of using `Set` and how would it solve my problem?

Comment: To start with, you can prevent duplicates automatically using a Set. For another thing, confirming that an object is within the set can be faster. And for a third thing, it makes it easier to combine underlying collections (collections of SteamEngines, DieselEngines) in a single set if you don't need a defined order on the combined collection. How does this help solve your problem? Using a Set of underlying collections, you can use the set for operations on all RollingStock, but when you just want Engines, you can just use that collection, rather than having to filter as per Frisch's answer

Comment: Thank you, that will solve my problem. Can I still sort a set when I list all trains for example (by its ID)? And how can I merge all my sets? MergeSets() can only be used to merge two sets, right?

Comment: Sets are defined as unordered, and sorting has no meaning. What you could do is use List.addAll(...) to add everything from the set to a list for sorting purposes. As far as merging, what I am proposing is that you create a class that implements `Set` and implement `Set`s methods using the other Collections that are a part of your larger `Set`

Answer (score 2):

Stream the list, filter for instances of `Engine`; map the instances from `RollingStock` to `Engine` (with a cast), collect the results into a new `List`. Like,

```
public List<Engine> returnEngines() {
    return rollingStocks.stream().filter(x -> x instanceof Engine)
            .map(x -> (Engine) x).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but using instanceof is bad coding style, isn't it? Could I instead use getClass() or isInstance()?

Comment: It's bad to check types at runtime, not so much a matter of coding style. `.filter(Engine.class::isInstance)` would also work (but is effectively the same as what I posted).

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Elliott Frisch is perfectly valid, here is a generified solution, in case you need also a method to filter your register for any type of your hierarchy:

```
public <T> List<T> returnClazz(Class<T> clazz) {
    return rollingStocks.stream()
            .filter(clazz::isInstance)
            .map(clazz::cast)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Which then can be used by several helper methods, e.g.

```
public List<TrainSet> returnTrainset() {
    return returnClazz(TrainSet.class);
}

public List<Engines> returnEngines() {
    return returnClazz(Engine.class);
}
...
```

or can be called directly.